# Check $ORACLE_HOME var in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

i am running script as root and trying to see if user oracle has ORACLE_HOME defined. here is my script:

```
su - $user << EOF  2>&1
    if [ -n "${ORACLE_HOME:+x}" ]
    then
        echo "KO" > /tmp/oracle.tmp
    else
        echo "$ORACLE_HOME" > /tmp/oracle.tmp
    fi
EOF
```

this doesnt work. it gives me `if: Expression Syntax.` and the file is not created. i think the problem is with the `su` encapsulation since when i am running the `if` statement alone it is working. any idea ?

And please don't ask me why i am running as root. i know its bad practice but there is nothing i can do about it.

Comment: Why not just: echo ${ORACLE_HOME:-KO} > /tmp/oracle.tmp  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is probably not run in bash, but in sh that does not support the alternate value syntax.

Comment: so do you have any suggestion to make it as much generic as possible so it would run in any shell ?

Comment: Well, you can replace it with [ -n "$ORACLE_HOME" ] that should work as well (why do you need alternate value here, anyway?) Or, run the code in bash.

Comment: I just want to check if the variable is set under oracle user. The problem is that i have no control over what shell oracle user is running so when i switch to it i need my commands to be as generic as possible. i don't know what alternate value is, i am a beginner in shell scripting... i will try what you suggest thanks.

Comment: okay i tried it and it gives the same result. i see now that root is running bash and oracle user is running tcsh so i guess tcsh does not know of this if syntax...

Comment: @michael: tcsh syntax is significantly different from sh/bash syntax. Most non-trivial scripts cannot run in both.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the quotes are getting stripped by the shell parsing the heredoc, so the code being executed is:

```
if [ -n ]
```

To eliminate that problem, you want to avoid string interpolation in the heredoc, which you can do by quoting the delimeter:

```
su - $user << 'EOF'  2>&1
```

Of course, that will prevent ORACLE_HOME from being interpolated, so this will only work if ORACLE_HOME is in the environment (that is, it is not a shell variable, but has been exported and is an environment variable.)

Unless the sample code given in the question is a simplification, you could just do:

```
echo ${ORACLE_HOME:-KO} > /tmp/oracle.tmp
```